# Why simple react hello world isn't working?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I just started learning React from that tutorial https://scrimba.com/p/p7P5Hd/cV7M2uR on scrimba.com, but I have a weird problem. When i work with a code inside of build in editor all works fine but when I tried to write **exact the same code** in my Visual Studio Code it just didn't work.

index.html file :

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="index.pack.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and index.js file:

```js
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

ReactDOM.render(<div><h1>Hello World</h1><p>This is a paragraph</p></div>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

The file style.css is practically completely empty.
So what am I missing or do wrong? There are some files I should download first, or maybe some other additional code or hidden settings to make it work? 
I tried to launch it both by liveserwer and just opening the index.html file - in both cases I just get completely blank webpage

Comment: Do you have something that builds the project? Just creating the index.html and index.js files isn't enough.

Comment: I just tried your code and It is working fine. go check it again

Comment: You can follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122386/2873538 or https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html for the steps to start with a react project.

Comment: @GuyIncognito no, the tutorial I was doing didn't use anything to build. It was just it - writing that lines of code and it started working without any building of a project. So I didn't think it is in any way necessery. So how should I build this project with just this two files (+yet empty css file)?

Comment: @Ben96 with what browser? I tried it again (twice other more times...) and it didn't work. i rechecked if any adblock or something (what maybe would prevent scripts from loading) is disabled but it didn't help too. I tried on Google Chrome, Comodo Dragon, Brave and CryptoTab Browser.

Comment: If the tutorial doesn't explain how to set up a new project on your own computer, it's not a very good tutorial. The online editor is obviously set up property because it's made just for this purpose. Follow https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html to set up a project.

Comment: by the way, it's still working, I use Google chrome latest version, but the issue is not related to the browser, you need to copy the content of `index.js` and paste it there in Scrimba, then you have to refresh that small browser `simulator` and it should work. wish this help you.

Comment: @Ben96 Scrimba is not the problem, the OP says it works just fine. The problem is that it doesn't work locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my humble opinion you should check out [Create React App](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) for learning React. As the website says:

> Create React App is a comfortable environment for learning React, and is the best way to start building a new single-page application in React.
>
> It sets up your development environment so that you can use the latest JavaScript features, provides a nice developer experience, and optimizes your app for production.

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Well I tried that link, but it is one problem with that... it create a whole react project with bunch of elements I don't even know what to do with them, and how they work, which make me kinda confused with it all.
I know it would be most likely very usefull when creating some real react project, when all of it would really be needed, but for starting with it, it seems a bit overwhelming. (I think that it's better to start simple and then get to this more structured project)

Comment: Also when starting project with that I see many other things even in index.js, and also no index.html, so I'm completely lost on how to open the website I'm building...

Comment: There are fine tutorials (expecting no prior experience with React) on that site. Look around and you find what you need to know! To start the local dev-environment just run `npm start` in the project dir..

Answer (score 0):

Because in Scrimba you import React as well as ReactDOM from the dependencies that are files already installed in your Scrimba project folder and are not available in your VS Code so I recommend to watch a tutorial on youtube on how to set up the environment for React JS.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32375579)

Answer (score 0):

Use `<script src="index.js"></script>` instead of `<script src="index.pack.js"></script>`. That should work just fine on local environment. Reason `index.pack.js` is not working because behind the scenes on scrimba editor they are using webpack, so it’s a little bit of Scrimba related logic which is working on online editor.